# Java gson.fromJson() to POJO using Reflection causes java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having a bit of a nightmarish issue parsing some JSON using Gson.

The Json structure I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
{ "user_id" : "833", "message" : "User created and registered" }
```

When I parse the Json using the following code:

```
Type response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<RestResponse>(){}.getType());
```

I receive the following error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: ... RestResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type

I am parsing into the following POJO:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class RestResponse {

    private void RestResponse() {
        // Constructor required for GSON
    }

    private StatusCode statusCode;
    private String content;
    private Object data;
    private Type output;
    private String user_id;
    private String message;
    private String error;

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.user_id;
    }
    public void setUserID(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getMessage() { return this.message; }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getError() { return this.error; }
    public void setError(String error) { this.error = error; }
    public StatusCode getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(StatusCode statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public final String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public final void setContent(final String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public final Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public final void setData(final Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public final Type getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
    public final void setOutput(final Type output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", this.content);
    }
}
```

The reason I am returning a Type as opposed to the RestResponse object is because I am calling a callback depending upon the type of response Type. I then process the code like so:

```
if (statusCode == StatusCode.SUCCESS) {
    if (requestCode == AppConstants.REQUEST_REGISTRATION) {
        if (data instanceof RestResponse) {
            RestResponse restResponse       = (RestResponse) data;
            AppDelegate delegate            = (AppDelegate) getApplicationContext();
            delegate.name                   = nameText.getText().toString();
            delegate.email                  = emailText.getText().toString();
            delegate.mobile                 = validatedFormattedNum;
            delegate.referredID             = "";
            delegate.isRegistered           = 1;
            delegate.uid                    = restResponse.getUserID();
            delegate.setInMemory();
        } else {
            if(data instanceof ApiErrorResponse) {
                ApiErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = (ApiErrorResponse) data;
                ...
                ...
                ...
```

A stack trace is here should anybody like to see:

```
E/com.sourgun.http.AppParser: General exception encountered in parse()    com.sourgun.http.RestResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type
04-22 12:51:13.748 31779-31779/? W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sourgun.http.RestResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type
04-22 12:51:13.748 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.sourgun.http.AppParser.parse(AppParser.java:37)
04-22 12:51:13.749 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.sourgun.http.RestController.onResponse(RestController.java:85)
04-22 12:51:13.750 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.sourgun.http.AsyncTaskExecutor.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskExecutor.java:66)
04-22 12:51:13.750 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.sourgun.http.AsyncTaskExecutor.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskExecutor.java:14)
04-22 12:51:13.751 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
04-22 12:51:13.751 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
04-22 12:51:13.752 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
04-22 12:51:13.753 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 12:51:13.753 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-22 12:51:13.754 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
04-22 12:51:13.754 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-22 12:51:13.755 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-22 12:51:13.755 31779-31779/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What is `response`? Is it a variable of type `Type`? Why?

Comment: Sorry, response is a Type

Comment: Why is it a `Type`? Why isn't it a `RestResponse`?

Comment: And what don't you understand about the exception message?

Comment: So @Pillar, do you think that is the issue? It is a Type as I process the response in another class

Comment: Yes, of course it is. `RestResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type`. You're returning a `RestResponse` but trying to assign it to a `Type`.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to populate the object from the Json String using reflection so I can not return a RestResponse object, I need to return a type. An alternative route is to return a APIErrorResponse type i.e.     Type errorType = new TypeToken<ApiErrorResponse>(){}.getType();    response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, errorType);

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `fromJson` accepts a `Type` argument, but returns the declared type in the type token.

Comment: It's the first time I have come across this in code, i.e. trying to convert from a String into an object of type RestResponse using reflection, do you know of another way to do it?

Comment: Like found here: http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/#json_to_java

Comment: I don't understand who down voted me, and for what reason. I thought Stack Exchange was a place to ask and answer questions. What's wrong with my question?

Comment: There are two ways with Gson. One is `RestResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<RestResponse>(){}.getType());` which is what you have except change the variable type from `Type` to `RestResponse`. Or use one of the solutions below, ie. `RestResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, RestResponse.class);`

Comment: The downvote must be because the exception is literally telling you what is wrong. And more or less tells you how to fix it.

Comment: @Pillar I find that very small minded that someone, who may not have understood what I was trying to do would vote down my question because they don't know what they don't know.

Comment: I have solved my own problem, there were actually two errors in my code preventing this from working. These errors were that the RestResponse class should have been defined as public class RestResponse implements Type { whilst I thought I had a constructor but it had a return type of void, so the public constructor should have been: public RestResponse() {}

Comment: Having said this, I do thank Pillar and KishuDroid for their assistance

Comment: Although, technically, that's one way not to get a `ClassCastException` in your scenario, can you explain why you need a `Type` in the first place? According to the javadoc, [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) _is the common superinterface for all types_. Your `RestResponse` class doesn't feel like a `Type` at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109965/discussion-between-mat-and-pillar).

Comment: @Pillar I could not fit my response to you in the comments section so I edited my original answer to include the additional clarification you sought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the RestResponse was not defined correctly, it should have been defined as (including the implements Type, and a correct public constructor):

```
 public class RestResponse implements Type {

    public RestResponse() {}

    ...
    ...
```

For brevity's sake I did not include all imports into the above original code, something which may have made things clearer if I had done so.

There are 2 imports in my "parsing" class which are specific to the type Type, one is: **java.lang.reflect.Type** and the other is ***[com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)***. The TypeToken essentially hints at the type of Object that the de-serialization process will marshall the data into, which is assigned to a **java.lang.reflect.Type** typed variable.

There is nothing special about the RestResponse class, the reason that the Type import is required is that I am storing the marshalled Type in the **java.lang.reflect.Type** typed class member variable named "output".

Comment: Would the user who voted this answer down, for who knows what reason, please mark the answer as correct? Otherwise, please clarify the reason why you have voted this answer down given that the answer is in fact the correct answer for the specific circumstance encountered.

Comment: I'm still confused. What use do you have for a value of type `Type` after the deserialization is completed?

Comment: So, depending upon the returned type, If for e.g. it's a RestResponse Type, which can checked with an instanceof test, I can safely cast the Type to a concrete instance, access the returned data from the object. If the returned Type is of ApiErrorResponse Type, or any other type, then after checking with instanceof and casting to concrete obj I can take action based upon the data in that given object type. So, I can return different object types and capture only the data which I am interested in, which makes it a very flexible way of working with data coming in over the wire, or input stream.

Comment: So, @Pillar how about an upvote after all of this? Somebody has downvoted not only my question, but my answer too! It sucks! I wish I knew who it was!

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated a need for `Type`, specifically. `Object` would be more appropriate. Better yet, define your own superclass/superinterface for your `*Response` classes. Using `instanceof` is an anti pattern in most cases so you should be avoiding that anyway. Your call above returns a value of type `RestResponse` so you already know what it is. You don't need to reverify it. `Type` should only be involved when creating the type token. It isn't needed anywhere else.

Comment: Mate, I am done and dusted and don't really want to pursue this with you but thank you for your input to date. I had an issue, I solved it. Now, how about an upvote, or at least a change of downvote on both question and answer? All this superfluous fluff just isn't necessary.

Comment: Please don't ask for votes. It's 2 downvotes, don't stress. Here, I don't think you deserve an upvote. You're doing yourself a disservice and promoting bad practice (you haven't convinced me you need it) by implementing `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for getting ClassCaseException:

> That is because the class JsonParsing the method "parse" we call
>   gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken(){}.getType())
>   which will convert the String into java objects using Reflection.

Sot try below code:

```
RestResponse mRestResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, RestResponse.class));
```

See detail [description](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON) of parsing JSON using GSON.

With this approach, you can reuse the Response class to add any other additional fields to pick up other data members you might want to extract from JSON

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Now can you please explain why they were getting the exception they got?

Comment: With this approach, you can reuse the Response class to add any other additional fields to pick up other data members you might want to extract from JSON

Comment: What? I'm asking why your solution doesn't cause a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: That is because  the class JsonParsing the method "parse" we call 

gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<RestResponse>(){}.getType())

which will convert the String into java objects using Reflection.

Comment: @Pillar: Check above comment for your question.

Comment: You should be putting that in your answer, but it still doesn't explain why OP is seeing a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109746/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-pillar).

Comment: I was trying to convert the String into an object using reflection

Comment: Not yet KishuDroid, I will give it a try

Comment: so please try it and then lemme know.

Comment: Hello @KishuDroid I have tried your suggestion but have now come up against the following situation: 1)The record in the database is created (as before); 2) The mRestResponse is null (different from before); 3) java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference. I could really use your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109863/discussion-between-mat-and-kishudroid).

Answer (score -1):

you have a RestResponse class,

when you do this:

```
response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<RestResponse>(){}.getType());
```

is because you want to get from the json String some kind of class token, THAT is the error... **you want/need an object and only one** object of the class  **RestResponse**, so you need to do:

```
response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, RestResponse.class);
```

Comment: This is wrong. `Gson` has a `fromJson` overload that accepts a `Type`. This is used primarily to allow generic types to be deserialized correctly. However it can still be used for non generic types, as is done here. You do lose type safety though, which makes the error obvious `java.lang.ClassCastException: ... RestResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type`. They're are assigning the result, which is a `RestResponse`, to a `Type` (the type of the `response` variable), which is not allowed. This is all in the comments by the way.